# Is there a way to give someone the edit privilege before they reach 1000 rep?

Tags: discussion, support, editing, users, suggested-edits

I have noticed that user47149 keeps submitting very large amounts of good suggested edits to the queue. However that user has less than 1000 rep. Is there a way to make that user bypass needing edit approval?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. But approved edits give 2 points per edit, so approving their edits will work.

There is an exception, to have them elected as moderator, but...

Answer (score 4):

It is really heartwarming to wake up and find such an appreciative post about oneself. Thank you.

I would also like to use this "official" occasion to offer my apologies to you. In my first days on this site I was not being the nicest to you and I am sorry for that.

And of course it is possible to give someone that privilege before the required reputation threshold. Technically possible, I mean. After all, the network operates as a programmable computer system that behaves exactly as the SE programmers have told it to. If one convinces the programmers to insert a software modification in the form of an exception in the conditional statement that checks whether or not the 1000 point threshold has been reached, then the programmers could make a specific user exempt from that 1000 point threshold requirement.

Problem is, the procedure for doing such a thing is not standarized and probably nobody has done it before within this network. It would be like diving into the mechanical guts of a car, installing some sort of home-made voice-recognition device inside, and rewiring the ignition system to cooperate with said device so that one specific person could start the engine just using their voice. Another analogy could be tinkering with a microwave oven so that it continues to run even after opening the door, but only if the food being cooked happens to be one specific brand of popcorn.

If you are the exclusive owner of those devices, you could do that even though it is probably a bad idea; if the car or the microwave oven are used commercially in some sort of business like a large restaurant, nobody is going to risk adding such modifications.

And what is more, I suspect it could be not only as a privilege, but also as a curse because it prevents a person from earning reputation points for the edits. In my opinion, it is a pleasant dopamine hit each time you see the emerald-colored pop-up message appear, signifying that the reviewers deemed your suggestion helpful. It also helps a lot of people further their progress with these fancy review-related badges.

And to address the technical aspect of the question, I would like to mention one possibility not included in the existing answer, namely becoming a SE employee. However, such a scenario is something that my chronically-unemployed butt has never been dreaming about; I am just not economically-viable from the point of view of employers, I guess.

Comment: Down voters are optimally expected to reveal themselves and leave short diatribes in the comments explaining the thinking process behind their decision. Assuming those down voters care about improving the site's quality, that is.